# How to set a custom resolution on amd graphics card?

Tags: resolution, amd-radeon

I have a r9 290x graphics card. I am trying to run an application at 1366x768, however I am not able to add this resolution to my computer, and the application is defaulting to 1024x768. I ruled out the possibility of the monitor being to problem as this application runs fine on a another computer with an nvidia graphics card. If it matters though, the native resolution of the monitor is 2560x1440. The only other difference between the computer that works and the one that doesn't is that the nvidia one is running windows 7, and the amd one is running windows 10. I am using the same dual link dvi cable in both cases. Is there some sort of setting for amd that you have to set for this to work? I already tried setting "Enable GPU up-scaling" and "Enable virtual super resolution" in catalyst control center. Any  help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure but think that this is either impossible completely or without software. http://www.ehow.com/how_7649449_add-custom-resolution-ati.html

Answer (score 3):

First, upscaling isn't useful for what you're trying to do. I would put it back to the default.

Second, Virtual Super Resolution (like nVidia's Dynamic Super Resolution) will disable your ability to use custom resolution, as it is meant for rendering at a higher resolution than your monitor supports. and then down-scaling it to the monitor's native resolution. Not what you're after.

There is a method which works for AMD cards by suiken_2mieu at WSGF forums.
You must edit the `DALNonStandardModesBCD1` binary data in the registry.

1. Open this key`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CLASS\`
2. Search for the value `DALNonStandardModesBCD1`
3. Once found, edit its binary data.

   Each row represents a resolution. The first 2 bytes are the X length in pixels, the next 2 bytes are the Y length.

   The following 3 bytes are all NULL (0x00) and the 8th byte is the refresh rate.

The step-by-step can be found here.
http://www.wsgf.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=21972&sid=ac2efa7eafb57c60e741b9e022fe3f93&start=20

I've WayBacked the link in case it is ever to die.
https://web.archive.org/web/20151220012042/http://www.wsgf.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21972